# BigInteger to Hexadecimal

Tags: c#, hex, biginteger

Quick question...

I have a stupidly long `BigInteger` which I would like to write to a file as a hex string.

I know Java provides the `.toString(16)` method which does this, but I can't find an equivalent in C#.

I'm using `System.Numerics.BigInteger` from .NET 4.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `.ToString("X")` or `.ToString("x")` depending on what case you prefer.

Comment: For converting BigInteger to binary, hexadecimal and octal see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048476/#15447131

Comment: Would you pls tell sth about what is different between X and x ?!

Comment: Beware leading zeros

Comment: How to remove the leading zeros?

Answer (score 5):

Can you not use `yourBI.ToString("X")`?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268260.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
yourBI.ToString("x17").Substring(1) // If you need 16 length
```