# C# Convert a number larger than Int64 to HexaDecimal

Tags: c#, .net, hex, int64

I am trying to convert a big number(ex: 9407524828459565063) to Hexadecimal(ex: 828E3DFD00000000) in C#.

The problem is that the number is larger than Int64's max value.

i looked up everywhere and couldn't find a working solution.

Any help over here?

Thank you.

Comment: If it's bigger than int64, how are you *receiving* it?  Text?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use the System.Numerics.BigInteger class to do this.  The exact solution depends on the format in which you have this number: string, double, other.

If string (`s`):

```
var bigInt = BigInteger.Parse(s);
var hexString = bigInt.ToString("x");
```

If double (`d`):

```
var bigInt = new BigInteger(d);
var hexString = bigInt.ToString("x");
```

... etcetera.

Comment: BigInteger was introduced in .Net 4.0, so if you can use it then you can convert [BigInteger to Hexadeximal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988858/biginteger-to-hexadeximal)

Comment: I discovered `BigInteger.ToString("X")` sometimes adds a leading zero. I have created extension methods to convert to hex, binary and octal (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048476/#15447131) which do not include any leading zero.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps:

```
BigInteger b = 9407524828459565063;
var hex = b.ToString("X2");
```

Or

```
ulong l = 9407524828459565063;
var hex = l.ToString("X2");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .NET 4.0, you might have a look at the BigInteger class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx

```
  BigInteger bi = new BigInteger();
  bi = 9407524828459565063;
  string bix = bi.ToString("X");
```