# How can I convert HUGE Numbers in different bases to a binary representation in C#?

Tags: c#, binary, radix

I have two numbers. 5437 in **base 8** and  6312817211 in **base 256** for example.. How can I convert both of these to a ***binary representation***? I know how to convert the **5437**, that is easy, but I want a algorithm that will deal with **both** as I can not convert the larger number because it wont fit in a `int`, it will only fit in a `BigInteger` which I don't think has any built in ways to convert a `BigInteger` of **base 256** to a binary representation (**base 2)**. Any advice or help would be great. I'm out of ideas and my brain is about to explode.

(I'm working in C# btw)

Comment: This discusses BigInteger to binary at length in it's first answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048476/biginteger-to-hex-decimal-octal-binary-strings

Comment: So what characters are used to represent the 256 different digits?  Are you sure you're really working with base 256?

Comment: You will most likely need to write your own converter. Which isn't hard to do, if you know how different bases work.

Comment: Are you using all the 8-bit ASCII characters with their associated `int` values as the digits?  The formula is just the sum of each digits value times 256 to the power of that digits index starting at 0 on the right and increasing to n-1 on the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea how you're representing base256 integers, but if you've managed to convert them to `BigInteger`, you can use a converter like this.

```
static string ToBinary(BigInteger val) {
    if (val < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(val));
    if (val == 0) return "0";

    var bits = new List<char>();
    while (val > 0) {
        bits.Insert(0, ((val & 1) == 1) ? '1' : '0');
        val >>= 1;
    }
    return string.Concat(bits);
}
```